# mdadm raid 5 missing partitions after reboot

Tags: data-recovery, raid, mdadm, raid5

I had a working raid 5 array that had a whole debian install on it (I set it up during a debian install). I'd been using it a couple of days, all was fine, but since I created it during debian install, the raid array itself had 2 partitions on it, one for GPT and the big ext4 with the OS and everything on it.

After a lot of reading, it seems having your OS on the mdadm managed raid array is a bad idea. Since if there is a drive failure, you will have no OS to fix it. So I unplugged all my drives, grabbed an old one from the closet, and installed debian on that as the sole disk in the machine.

Once installed, I plugged my raid drives back in. Ran `mdadm --assemble --scan` and setup my `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` so it assembles on boot. All was pretty good, I could `mount -t ext4 /dev/md0p2 /mnt` and see all my data. Happy days.

So I added it to `/etc/fstab` and rebooted.

But after reboot, `/dev/md0p2` (and md0p1) don't exist anymore. Only `/dev/md0` is there. Not sure where the 2 partitions have gone!

Completely weird that I can re-assemble the array with no worries, it doesn't complain one bit. But the 2 partitions that were there are gone. I'm not even sure what `/dev/md0p1` was for. It concerned me when I first set it up, fdisk told me it was of type `GPT`.

Some command outputs to help:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdf1[0] sdb1[4] sdc1[5] sdd1[6] sde1[7] sdi1[3] sdh1[2] sdg1[1]
      5860147200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>


$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri May 23 14:05:16 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 8
  Total Devices : 8
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Sun May 25 18:15:26 2014
          State : active
 Active Devices : 8
Working Devices : 8
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : doc:0  (local to host doc)
           UUID : 11d6a8a7:d05a8c58:41fab15a:0b177f69
         Events : 25704

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       81        0      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       1       8       97        1      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       2       8      113        2      active sync   /dev/sdh1
       3       8      129        3      active sync   /dev/sdi1
       7       8       65        4      active sync   /dev/sde1
       6       8       49        5      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       5       8       33        6      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       4       8       17        7      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

---

**UPDATE**: I just realise the order of those disks in the array aren't what they used to be. It should start at `/dev/sdb1`. I've done a `mdadm --create --level=5 --num-devices=8 /dev/md0 /dev/sd[b-i]1` to re-create the array. This has inadvertantly put /dev/sdi1 into recovery. Yuck.

Now that I think back, I'm not entirely sure what the order should be. It's either alphabetical, or it's e,d,c,b,f,g,h,i which is odd. First 4 in reverse alphabetical, next for in normal alphabetical. I may have moved sata cables around when I plugged them back in, not sure.

Comment: ***Never*** ever do a `mdadm --create` to fix things. drive letters may change, drive order in mdadm metadata does not. Furthermore, `mdadm` defaults like offsets changed over time, so chances are high that you won't see your old data with the newly created array, even if you got the drive order right.

Comment: The metadata you posted above says `Fri May 23 14:05:16 2014` for creation time, so unless you actually created this thing yesterday, you lost your partition data and such to a botched `mdadm --create`. Additional or complete data loss through metadata/sync/recovery is possible.

Comment: I created it on Friday, those times are correct. It's now Sunday here in AU. I've found many stackexchange responses to suggest `mdadm --create` over the top is perfectly fine providing the metadata version is the same and you don't write anything to the new array (e.g. create a new partition).

Comment: When you `--create`, you must know all the variables the raid was originally created with, order, offset, chunk size, raid level, ... fixing things with `--create` is a bad idea because the ways you can fail with it are not obvious and a bad sync can kill everything.

Comment: Do you have to rescue any data off this thing? If not, I'd just do it over. As for the drive order, I prefer to use the order they are in the case, so identifying a bad drive is easy, e.g. if it's `[UU_UUUU]` you know to replace the 3rd drive in the case.

Comment: I have my important stuff backed up, but the rest is 10+ years of stuff that I could replace over the next 4-5 years I guess, but annoying as hell and will happily pay to restore it if I have to.

Should I stop sdi1 from recovering? I think I can do that with some /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action magic. I can remove it from the array too if it is just going to continue to want to recover.

Comment: The answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/347606/recover-raid-5-data-after-created-new-array-instead-of-re-using is where i got the idea to re-create the array in a different drive order... amazingly well written and makes perfect sense

Comment: You started with needing to add `--auto=mdp` to a mdadm line somewhere (to get `md0pX` instead of `md0`), and now you instead get to figure out your array geometry. Note the 'infinite wisdom' in the Serverfault question is sarcastic; the person asking that question realizes it was a bad idea. You have the Serverfault answer about figuring out the geometry to use now... And do note its bold line up top about a backup. In the future, **DO NOT USE `--create` TO REPAIR YOUR ARRAY.**

Comment: @tigris please point where you read the use of `mdm --create` to recover data in AU. I'm hereby going to downvote that answer.

Comment: BTW: Please point out the Stack Exchange answers suggesting `--create` is anything but a last-resort data recovery attempt to be used only after trying everything else and to be attempted only after imaging the drives. I'd like to go fix them.

Comment: The answer on serverfault led me to believe doing a `--create` of what I suspected to be the correct order would allow me to check if a filesystem would then present itself. If not, i could just `--create` back to the original order with no harm done. I will read up with `--auto=mdp` does, as absolutely nothing I found in 12 hours of searching suggested to try this, so as you say, I was at my "last resort" already.

Comment: @tigris, whatever you do, don't `--create` again. don't change anything. The way I understand your story so far, your correct drive order is what you pasted above; and since you used `--create` in the same session, we have the drive order even if drive letters change again, as long as you don't kill the new metadata you have now. If you like you can talk to me on IRC FreeNode #linux-raid

Comment: @frostschutz i don't intend on it, do i wait for sdi1 to recover? i assume it's currently being filled with parity bits, parity of what though since we aren't sure what's on the other drives

Comment: I've sent off some request for quotes to 4-5 data retrieval mobs around my local area. Will see what prices come back tomorrow. Willing to go as high as about $400 i reckon. Probably not gonna find anyone to do it for that price, never know. That's about how much I saved by choosing raid 5 over raid 1 so seems reasonable haha.

Comment: @tigris, such companies are only really necessary when you suffer from hard drive failure.